# ProjectTo same instance in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

Here is my Domain Entity

```
public class Email
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cause
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CauseDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CauseName { get; internal set; }
    public string CauseEmail { get; set; }
    public string EmailName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefaultEmail { get; set; }
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Profile:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Cause, CauseDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CauseEmail, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Email))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CauseName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.UseDestinationValue());

        CreateMap<Email, CauseDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsDefaultEmail, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.IsDefault))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailId, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Project To Code:

```
 var causeDTO = ctx.Emails.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ProjectTo<CauseDTO>().FirstOrDefault();

 causeDTO = ctx.Causes.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ProjectTo<CauseDTO>(causeDTO).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the first query, I get the causeDTO result which is Mapped between Email and CauseDTO by Ignoring all other objects and in second query I have passed the same object to Map between Cause and CauseDTO applied ForAllOtherMembers to use the Destination Value. But it's not working. Destination value is not binding i.e.. EmailName, IsDefaultEmail, EmailId.

Can you please help me how to figure this out? I need both result on the same instance.